# Can't winphone be a socket server?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone

I just search too much article including MSDN about how to connect a server which is on PC. But I want two winphones communication without PC server. I look up MSDN about winphone socket and don't find the function like 'listen', 'bind'.
So is there some snippet about winphone as server?
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: DevTheo is right; [this is not supported](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/84416/508693.aspx#508693), though it's not easy to find it documented officially anywhere, even in [the security doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.96).aspx).  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickyt/archive/2011/06/15/windows-phone-peer-to-peer-multiplayer-game-using-sockets-in-xna.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286407(v=vs.92).aspx) are two UDP multicast examples, if that is a possibility.  I will delete the other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about win phone development but if you're looking for a way for the phone communication to work serverless, UDP might be a good option.

The platform almost certainly supports it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202864(v=vs.92).aspx